# Get an existing Captcha image via cURL

Tags: php, http, curl, request

I'm trying to get a Captcha(old, the image one) image from a web page. But, I know it always changes and being regenerated on every HTTP request. But I can't get the image via cURL.

I've tried this with this code in PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/login.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NETRC, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Image just comes as empty. There is field like Captcha but nothing is written on it. I couldn't understand if there is a difference between browser request or cURL request.

Comment: What site is this? The reCaptcha v1 API (i.e, "the image one") was shut down in March 2018. It's no longer available.

Comment: I called it reCaptcha. Normally it's a custom script that generates digits.

Comment: Then call it a CAPTCHA. reCAPTCHA is a specific service provided by Google, not a generic term. More importantly -- that means this is something site-specific, so we can't really give you any advice without knowing what site you're talking about in particular.